# Bain & Engelhardt Ex9.6: Wanted some advice/confirmation if the answer is correct.

Tags: probability, statistics, parameter-estimation

Q: Find MLE based on random sample $X_1, . . , X_n$ from the pdf $$f(x;\theta_1,\theta_2)=\frac{1}{\theta_2 - \theta1} ; \theta_1\le x \le \theta_2$$
and zero otherwise

A: \begin{align}
   \log f(x)= -\log {\theta_2-\theta_1}
   \end{align}
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_1}=\frac{1}{\theta_2-\theta_1}$$
which tells us that the log likelihood function is increasing in $\theta_1$ since the partial derivative $\ge0$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta_2}=\frac{1}{\theta_1-\theta_2}$$
which tells us that the log likelihhod function is decreasing in $\theta_2$ since the partial derivative $\le0$

Since we want to maximize likelihood, I think the answer should be $$\hat{\theta_1}= X_{1:n}$$
as $\theta_1 \le x$ and $$\hat{\theta_2}=X_{n:n}$$
as $x \le \theta_2$

Comment: Thelikelihood function is  $$f\left(\theta_1,\theta_2|{\bf x}\right) = \prod^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{\theta_2- \theta_1 }=\left(\frac{1}{\theta_2- \theta_1 } 
 \right)^{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE. The formal way is to say that :

$$L(\theta_1,\theta_2) = (\theta_2-\theta_1)^{-n}.$$

Then, as you noticed, the derivatives of $L$ with respect to $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are resp. decreasing and increasing. Then the likehood is maximized for

$$\hat{\theta_2} = \max_i x_i, ~\hat{\theta_1} = \min_i x_i. $$

Hope it helps.

Comment: At the question it is $\theta_2-\theta_1$.

Comment: When $\hat{\theta_1} = \max_i x_i$ it would mean that $\theta_1 \ge x$ 
Since the question holds that $\theta_1 \le x$ the maximum value considering this constraint can only be $X_{1:n}$ 
Or am I confusing something?

Comment: @KaTee i don't get your remark, could you reformulate it ?

Comment: If the estimate of the parameter is the maximum of the values in the given distribution, it would mean the parameter $\theta_1$ is greater than the realized values of X. 
In the question, its stated that $\theta_1 \le x \le \theta_2$. It would mean that whatever value we choose for the estimates of both the $\theta$, it should hold $\theta_1 \le \theta_2$. The maximum value of $x_i$ fulfilling this constraint is the smallest value in the distribution $X_{1:n}$.
Sorry for the confusion, maybe I'm making too much out of a simple question

Comment: Ok, my bad. I congused $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Sorry, I edit my post